Adding answer to closed question
I would like to post an answer to a closed question of mine which is Why isn't there an official docker image for QGIS server, i.e. released by QGIS.org.
How could I proceed?

Add a comment to the original question that you'd like to post an answer.  Flagging for moderator attention might help also.
Your original question is still off-topic, so will be re-closed with the same close reason, however if you have valuable information to add as an answer, there is no reason it can't be re-opened temporarily for you to add your answer.
